# Query to find occurrence of all characters in a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have column employeeid and employeename

```
ID   Name
1    Empee1
2    Emp1
```

I need o/p as

```
Name 
E - 3 m - 1 p - 1 1 - 1
E - 1 m - 1 1 - 1
```

Comment: This is not an easy operation to do in SQL.  And, your output format is not clear.  Is that one column per row?  A separate column per count?

Comment: To ask an On Topic questions, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Comment: @RiggsFolly If you are willing to help kindly don demotivate by ur comment

Comment: @GordonLinoff Separate column per count

Comment: This is best resolved in application code.

Comment: Might be able to make a relatively clean solution with a PIVOT.

Comment: yes @Strawberry but i need sql query to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a 'nice' way to do this, but the following would give you your result:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN [NAME] LIKE '%A%' THEN 'A - ' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, LEN([NAME]) - LEN( REPLACE ([NAME], 'A', '')))
  ELSE '' END,
  CASE WHEN [NAME] LIKE '%B%' THEN ' B - ' + CONVERT ( VARCHAR, LEN([NAME]) - LEN( REPLACE ([NAME], 'B', '')))
  ELSE '' END,
  ...
  ...
  CASE WHEN [NAME] LIKE '%Z%' THEN ' Z - ' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, LEN([NAME]) - LEN( REPLACE ([NAME], 'Z', '')))
  ELSE '' END,
  CASE WHEN [NAME] LIKE '%0%' THEN ' 0 - ' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, LEN([NAME]) - LEN( REPLACE ([NAME], '0', '')))
  ELSE '' END,
  ...
  ...
  CASE WHEN [NAME] LIKE '%9%' THEN ' 9 - ' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, LEN([NAME]) - LEN( REPLACE ([NAME], '9', '')))
  ELSE '' END
FORM [Your TABLE name];
```

Comment: Tanx @Gez Jones